# How to remove custom-header section of Tweenty Seventeen theme of Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to remove `custom-header` section that is automatically added at header section by Tweenty Seventeen theme.

I know I can do the following:

```
.custom-header{
    display: none;
}
```

But I do not want to remove it by CSS. I want to remove it via **functions.php**, instead.

I have searched on Tweenty Seventeen code and I have found that on the file `/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/inc/custom-header.php` is including custom-header section by `add_action` function.

The function is the following:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentyseventeen_custom_header_setup' );
```

So I have added the following function on my functions.php file of my Tweenty Seventeen Child theme:

```
function remove_custom_header() {
    remove_action('after_setup_theme', 'twentyseventeen_custom_header_setup');
}

add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_custom_header');
```

but it is still appearing.

I am using WP-Optimize plugin to cache files but I have cleared files and pre-load files and it is still appearing. I have guessed that if custom-header was being added by add_action I could use remove_action to avoid to be included.

What should I do to remove custom-header section via functions.php?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: change this code `add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_custom_header', 1);` and try. Do you want to remove header image or full header?

Comment: @Vel mmm... It makes a strange behaviour. It seems that is applying different styles when adding 1 as a last parameter, but it is still being shown. I mean, before adding 1 it is occupying space but not showing site-title and site-description inside site-branding section and after adding 1 it is showing them. I have looked at CSS and it is applying different styles but still shown it. I suppose that changing priority it is applying CSS before another CSS, but I do not understand why it is not removing the `customer-header` section. I thought it should have the same priority as add_action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I figured out what was happening. There are two parts of code that seems to load `custom-header` section on Tweenty Seventeen theme.

One, is the code that I have described on my question, but that was not the part of code that was affecting to me. If you want to override it, it should be enough to copy `remove_custom_header` function that I have added to my question.

Looking further, I have see that on header.php file there is a line that was loading `custom-header` section. The line I am talking about is the following:

```
get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/header', 'image' );
```

that is loading the file `/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/template-parts/header/header-image.php` which contains `custom-header` HTML code. I have copied header.php file to my child theme and removed that line. `custom-header` section have been removed with that.